# Knew, realized + the past/present

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses, agreement

Please consider the following:

> 1. I knew the building (IS/WAS) thirty feet tall.
> 2. They realized I (AM/WAS) his son.

My question: both those clauses contain general truths. So, do I need to use the present, or the past?

Answer (score 1):

If the clause after *knew* or *realized* is a general truth, or more specifically, if it is still true, we can use either the past or the present.

[This website](https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017), talking about backshifting, says

> Backshifting occurs not only with indirect speech, but also with reported feelings and thoughts expressed frequently with verbs such as know, think, realize, and forget.

and

> In certain situations, the sequence of tense rules are relaxed and backshifting is not required. Essentially, backshifting is not required if a statement about the present or future still holds. . . .

So the rules for verbs like *realized* and *knew* are the same as the reported speech: if the fact is still true, then you can use either the past or the present. In speech and writing,
we usually use the past unless there is some reason to emphasize that the fact is still true.

If you want an actual example in print, in [*New York Magazine*,](https://books.google.com/books?id=AsUDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22I+knew+he+was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9qOjPiqLhAhWEg-AKHVwGCPkQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22I%20knew%20he%20was%22&f=false) in 1972, Mario Puzo says about Francis Ford Coppola:

> That's when I knew he was really a director.

Coppola never stopped being a director. And Mario Puzo presumably spoke English well: he was born in New York, and is the author of the book *The Godfather*, and coauthor of *The Godfather* screenplay, which Coppola directed.

Comment: Yes. Swan in _Practical English Usage_ (p276) says: _After past reporting verbs, we usually change the original tenses even if the things the original speaker says are still true. 'I told the police I was British. (The speaker still is British')_.

Comment: @Shoe I agree with Peter’s answer but I think it can’t be supported to say what most English speakers say.  I’ve seen a lot of variations and situations which necessitate changing “rules.”

Comment: @michael_timofeev. Both Peter Shor above and Swan state that backshift '_usually_' takes place. And both Swan and _ThoughtCo_ say that backshift is not required if, in Swan's words, "_the original speaker's present and future are still present and future_". So in general I agree that it is unhelpful to talk of _rules_ at all in this context. But I'm not sure I agree that Peter's answer '_can't be supported by what most English speakers say_'. Perhaps I'll do some research on this if I can find the time.

Comment: Maybe I should comment more on that word *"usually"*. I would say that backshift is the default, but there are lots of situations where you make an exception because the fact that it's still true is relevant, important, or even just interesting.

Comment: @Shoe  I respect Swan as a source but the problem with researching this is how does one find out what st least a billion people consider normal or usually say?  It treats language as some kind of mathematical law which people are compelled to obey.  I think the answer is fine but this one is more open than other questions which are more cut and dried so to speak.  Google books is the wrong place to go for support as it is written language.

Comment: @michael_timofeev. There are spoken-language corpora that could provide some data. And Longman's _Grammar of Spoken and Written English_ is based on a corpus, so this would be good places to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, experts. I've got it. So, applying backshifting is much more common, though we cannot say the one without it is wrong, right? Copy that! :D

Comment: Peter, what if the sentence is like this: Rina (WAS/IS) a quick thinker so that she could dodge the swung knife. The event of dodging the knife happened in the past of course, but she is still a quick thinker till now. Could we use mixed tenses here? Should we use "is"?

Comment: @FadliSheikh: You can, but you don't have to.

Comment: Is there such a thing as "more common" in this case?

Comment: I think it depends on whether you think Rita's being a quick thinker is relevant to the present. If this happened in Venezuela, and she's back home now, I would probably use the past. But if this is something that might happen again, I would probably use the present. Of course, there's lots of ways something might be relevant to the present—that's just an example.

Comment: Okay, got it. By the way if someone replies with "my warmest regards for your husband" after seeing a photo, what does it possibly mean? The person uses "for" instead of "to".